# Subset of vector / C++ / STL

Tags: c++, vector, struct, stl, subset

I want to extract a subset of a vector filled with structs and form a new vector filled with only one member variable of that subset.

The main vector is filled with structs like this:

```
struct ImageParams{
    double startTime;
    double stopTime;
    std::string path;
    std::string activeInstrument;
    bool projected;
};
```

So say that my application has jumped from t0 -> t1, then I want every `startTime` in between t0 & t1. I currently loop over the main vector using a binary find operation and store each `startTime` in a new return vector like so:

```
captureTime = t1;   
while (captureTime > t0){
        auto binary_find = [](std::vector<ImageParams>::iterator begin,
            std::vector<ImageParams>::iterator end,
            const ImageParams &val,
            bool(*cmp)(const ImageParams &a, const ImageParams &b))->std::vector<ImageParams>::iterator{
            std::vector<ImageParams>::iterator it = std::lower_bound(begin, end, val, cmp);
            if (it != begin){
                return std::prev(it);
            }
            return end;
        };
        // Finds the lower bound in at most log(last - first) + 1 comparisons
        auto it = binary_find(mainVec.begin(), mainVec.end(), 
                             { captureTime, 0, "", "", false }, cmp);

        if (it == mainVec.end()) return false;
        if (it->startTime < t0) break;

        returnVec.push_back(it->startTime);

        captureTime = it->startTime - 1;
    }
```

**What I want do achieve:**
This works but I think it looks ugly with the while loop. I was thinking that perhaps there is an efficient way (provided one locates two iter-positions in the `mainVec` that match times t0 and t1) to form a new vector with only the `startTime` member variable.

I imagine something like this,

```
std::vector<double> returnVec = std::vector(mainVec.begin () + first,
                                            mainVec.begin () + last);
```

but where its possible to say "only extract the `startTime` member variable"

Perhaps im overthinking it?

Comment: use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using `std::transform`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct ImageParams {
    double startTime;
    double stopTime;
    std::string path;
    std::string activeInstrument;
    bool projected;
};

int main()
{
    // Our initial vector of ImageParams
    const std::vector<ImageParams> vec {
        { 1.0, 0.0, std::string(), std::string(), false },
        { 2.0, 0.0, std::string(), std::string(), false },
        { 3.0, 0.0, std::string(), std::string(), false },
        { 4.0, 0.0, std::string(), std::string(), false }
    };

    // A subset of our initial vector's startTimes
    std::vector<double> subset;
    std::transform(vec.begin() + 1, vec.end(),
                   std::back_inserter(subset),
                   [](const ImageParams& i) { return i.startTime; });

    // Print the subset
    std::cout << "subset contains: ";
    for (double d : subset) {
        std::cout << d << ' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
subset contains: 2 3 4
```

---

In its simplest form, `std::transform` accepts a range of elements (via first and last iterators), a destination iterator (here we use `std::back_inserter` to insert the result of our transformation function into the subset vector), and we pass it a lambda function to extract the start time of each `ImageParams` element.

Answer (score 1):

(Totally redid my answer in response to a comment - you can see the original in edit history).

You can do this with `std::transform` and a functor or lambda if you have C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct ImageParams
{
    double startTime;
    double stopTime;
    std::string path;
    std::string activeInstrument;
    bool projected;
};

struct ExtractStartTime
{
    double operator()(const ImageParams& params) const
    {
        return params.startTime;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ImageParams params = { 1.0, 0.0, std::string(), std::string(), false };

    std::vector<ImageParams> big_vec(5, params);
    big_vec[4].startTime = 5.0;

    std::vector<double> small_vec;

    std::transform(big_vec.begin() + 2, big_vec.end(), std::back_inserter(small_vec), ExtractStartTime());

    for(int i = 0; i < small_vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << i << "]: " << small_vec[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this possible to do without declaring the return vector as type std::vector<ImageParamsStart> but instead have it as std::vector<double> ? 
Ie from std::vector<ImageParams> get the range and extract only startTime member for each struct and pass them all directly to  std::vector<double> ?